# jsddm displays behind flot and becomes transparent

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm trying to create a page with JSDDM drop down menus and a flot graph.   The problem I have is that the jsddm drop down menu becomes transparent when it drops down over the graph canvas.   Is there a way to force jsddm drop down to always be on top and non-transparent?

```
<ul id="jsddm">
  <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Drop Down Menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">jQuery Plugin</a></li>
      <li class="b"><a href="#">Ajax Navigation</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">AJAXIFY</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Effect</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Slide Effect</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Fade Effect</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Opacity Mode</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Drop Shadow</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Semitransparent</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Navigation</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">HTML/CSS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
</ul>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dlong/74uhra02/)

Answer (score 2):

To make sure that the drop-down stays above the content, change its `z-index` value in your CSS. The background color is actually solid, it just appears transparent because of the way the other content is overlapping.

So in your case something like this should work:

```
#jsddm ul {
    z-index: 1000;
}
```